# installing scikit-learn in alpine

Tags: python, scikit-learn, alpine-linux

i am trying to install scikit-learn in an alpine image, python:3.9-alpine, but it is failing

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
RUN apk --update add gcc build-base freetype-dev libpng-dev openblas-dev py3-scikit-learn
RUN pip install scikit-learn
```

And this is the error i have when i install it

```
#8 237.6             FAILED: scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.p/meson-generated_..__stats_pythran.cpp.o
#8 237.6             c++ -Iscipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.p -Iscipy/stats -I../scipy/stats -I../../../pip-build-env-g1ms629a/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pythran
-I../../../pip-build-env-g1ms629a/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include
-I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fdiagnostics-color=always -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -std=c++14 -O3 -fPIC -DENABLE_PYTHON_MODULE -D__PYTHRAN__=3 -DPYTHRAN_BLAS_NONE -Wno-cpp -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-int-in-bool-context -MD -MQ scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.p/meson-generated_..__stats_pythran.cpp.o
-MF scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.p/meson-generated_..__stats_pythran.cpp.o.d
-o scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39-aarch64-linux-gnu.so.p/meson-generated_..__stats_pythran.cpp.o
-c scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpp
```

What is the right way to install it in an alpine image?

Comment: Try with `apk add py3-scikit-learn`

Comment: Since there is a reference to `aarch64-linux` in your error, are you building this image on a recent Mac?